Configure PyCharm to never run pytest on file
I often want to debug test files in PyCharm and find myself struggling to configure PyCharm to actually debug the file normally instead of running pytest on it on not stopping on any exception. All that to again, have it run pytest again by accident.
I'd like to configure my PyCharm to never run as pytest, always run/debug files normally instead. I'll run pytest from the terminal if I ever want to.
Is that possible?
